# DAL using typed dataset

Tags: dataset, typed

Are there any performance issues in using Typed Data Sets as DAL? Is it a recommended approach? I am using it for listing purposes only (repeater). It has paging, sorting functionalities too.

Comment: " Is it a recommended approach?" : To some extent, that depends on the particular circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

It works through untyped DataSet and just incapsulates type casting.

Answer (score 0):

A dataset includes a lot of information other than the data that you need in the list. Therefore, if you can read the data out in a different way it would give you less information to transfer and therefore better performance.

Having said that, depending on your app you may not notice the difference. Do whatever is easiest for you and then check the performance.